# Make gradle.properties available in Java

Tags: java, gradle

Question:  How can I make my test configuration information from the gradle.properties file available in java?

```
#gradle.properties file
#default browser configuration
browserName=chrome
browserVersion=latest

#default selenium configuration
seleniumHubURL=
seleniumPort=

#default environment configuration
envWebURL=
envAPIURL=
```

I figured I can add every property to the system properties and access it that way, but I figured there should be a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this plugin: https://github.com/mfuerstenau/gradle-buildconfig-plugin

I still feel like it's overkill to do something as simple as make build properties available at run time but after an hour of searching it seems like the best solution.